# Criar TZConneciton em run time

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, zeos

Boa tarde
Estou usando Delphi 7 com ZEOS.
Necessito criar uma conexao em RUN TIME.
Estou tentando usar o seguinte codigo

```
Var
  Connection : TZConnection;
begin    
    Connection:= TZConnection.Create(Nil);
    Connection.HostName:= '127.0.0.1';
    Connection.Database:= 'RMS';
    Connection.Password:= '1111';
    Connection.User:= 'root';
    Connection.Port:= 3306;
    Connection.Protocol:= 'mysql-4.1';
    Connection.LoginPrompt:= False;
    Connection.TransactIsolationLevel:= tiReadCommitted;
```

Mas por algum motivo a linha

> Connection.TransactIsolationLevel:= tiReadCommitted;

esta me retornando o seguinte erro

> [Error] Unit1.pas(719): Incompatible types:
>   'TZTransactIsolationLevel' and 'TTransIsolation'

A minha pergunta é..: 
Tenho que declarar algo no USES para poder SETAR o Connection.TransactIsolationLevel via programação ou 
via programação realmente não da para setar esta propriedade??
Em tempo de projeto eu consigo me conectar e mudar a propriedade acima citada normalmente.
Abraços e obrigado a todos pela atenção.

Comment: Qualquer coisa que você faz via design, você consegue fazer via código. A mensagem esta clara, ele esta esperando um tipo de dado e esta recebendo outro, mesma passando o enumerado correto para a propriedade. Então vamos lá, eu sugiro dar um "Ctrl+Click" no tiReadCommitted e ver aonde que ele esta pegando este valor, veja se ele esta mandando para a declaração correta dos fontes da ZeosLib e se o fonte esta no path esperado. Na versão que utilizo do zeos esta no fonte ZDbcIntfs, declarado como um TZTransactIsolationLevel, que é o mesmo tipo esperado pela propriedade TransactIsolationLevel

Comment: @Confundir Boa tarde.. Cara você foi de boa.. Foi só declarar a unit ZDbcIntfs
 que a parada funcionou.. O "Ctrl + Click" desde o inicio estava me mandando para o DBTables, por isso não funcionava...Brigadão pela atenção.. :) Abraços